# Count Nulls in a table and group by column name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically I have a table that I need to count the number of NULL values in each column and return the count for that each column along with that column's name. I can query each column individually but there are 191 columns in this table.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

This gets the Null value for one column but I would have to run this 190 more times to get all the rows:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TS_EQUIPMENTLOCATION
FROM dbo.USR_IT_PURCHASE_TRACKER
WHERE (TS_EQUIPMENTLOCATION IS NULL)
```

Comment: 190 more times? Do you really have almost 191 columns in your table? That sounds like the design phase didn't go as cleanly as it should have. But if you need to know the number of rows that have NULL for each column you are going to have to write a query that addresses each column. Using SUM with a case expression is about the easiest but requires 191 columns. You can leverage sys.columns to help you build the query.

Comment: That is exactly how I handled it.  I just ran a count for each column and replicated it 191 times.  Such a pain but it seemed to work when output as text.  This is COTS software so we weren't involved in the design.  Seemed somewhat ridiculous to me to have that many columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use case when with aggregate function sum()

```
SELECT sum(case when TS_EQUIPMENTLOCATION IS NULL then 1 else 0 end )
AS TS_EQUIPMENTLOCATION    
FROM dbo.USR_IT_PURCHASE_TRACKER
```